# BufferedReader inputstream blocks only until it receives the first input

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am using sockets to implement instant messaging.

I have the following Java code on the client side:

```
while ( true )
    checkInputStream();
```

Here's the function:

```
private void checkInputStream() throws IOException
{   
    //prints once, but after the first input arrives, it prints infinitely
    Log.i( "MY_TAG", "CHECKING INPUT STREAM");
    String inputLine;

    //inputStream is a BufferedReader object
    while ((inputLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) 
    {
                //code                                                                                       
    }   
}
```

**Problem**

The behavior I'm getting is that `readline()` blocks until it receives the first input (which is fantastic).  But as soon as I send it its first message terminating in a newline character, it loops over and over again regardless if I've seen sent any more input.

**Question**

Is this normal behavior?

If yes, how can I get `readline()` to block until more input arrives?

**Why I care**

The reason I would like it to keep blocking like it does for the first input is because I can feel the android phone I'm testing with overheat.

Comment: Instead of checking again as soon as you see nothings there, why not wait a few seconds before checking again?

Comment: @Epicblood Because then it wouldn't be "instant" messaging.

Comment: I suggest you look into some of the event based socket packages such as [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Comment: @Epicblood It's a blocking method. It should block while there is no input.

Comment: I see no reason something HAS to be blocked, that just sounds like poor coding.

Comment: @Epicblood  'Poor coding' has nothing to do with it. All `java.io` streams are defined as blocking, and blocking means that input blocks until input is available, and output blocks until it is complete. This is the default I/O behaviour in every computer system I have used in about 44 years.

Comment: @ejp I mean there is no reason to create a spin lock while waiting for new input. You should be able to use an async event based socket.

Comment: @Epicblood Nobody said anything about 'creating a spin lock'. You're just making this up. OP can use a blocking socket, just like most everybody else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I get readline() to block until more input arrives?

It *does* block until more input arrives. Your problem is that you're calling it in two nested loops, one of which ignores end of stream

Remove the outer `while (true)` loop. You're already looping until end of stream inside the method. If you loop calling the method as well you will spin forever at end of stream.

Comment: I would only be able to receive 1 message if I did that.

Comment: @KacyRaye Nonsense. The inner loop on `readLine()`.will read everything until the peer closes the connection.

Comment: I shall try it and get back to you.

Comment: You were 100% correct.  The readline() method is blocking correctly until a new message arrives.  And I did not need the external while loop.
And for what it's worth, I had a small bug in my server-side code.  In php, I had `strlen($buf + 1)` instead of `strlen($buf) + 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the while(true) loop from the code

Comment: @Fahim readLine() automatically blocks until the next input arrives.  The reason it was looping infinitely I think was because of the small bug I had on the server side.  No need for a timer.

Comment: @Fahim `readLine()` blocks until some input arrives, or end of stream, or an exception, along with every other read method in `java.io`. It's a blocking-mode API. You really should know this. The reason it was looping indefinitely was because the outer loop was ignoring end of stream. It wasn't necessary in the first place.